# How to parse a XML string from webservice using C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

At bovespa website have a webservice with stock quotes informations

http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/Pregao-Online/ExecutaAcaoAjax.asp?CodigoPapel=petr4

```
<ComportamentoPapeis>
    <Papel Codigo="PETR4" 
           Nome="PETROBRAS PN" 
           Ibovespa="#" 
           Data="10/07    /201400:00:00" 
           Abertura="17,78" 
           Minimo="0,00" 
           Maximo="18,17" 
           Medio="17,97" 
           Ultimo="18,11"      
           Oscilacao="4,50" 
           Minino="17,62"/>
</ComportamentoPapeis>
```

I am trying to read this xml and navigate into him using this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace stock_analysis
{
    class Teste
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            const string URL = "http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/Pregao-Online/ExecutaAcaoAjax.asp?CodigoPapel=petr4";
            // Create a request for the URL. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (URL);
            // If required by the server, set the credentials.
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
            // Display the status.
            //Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
            // Display the content.

            //Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams and the response.

            //StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();


            String xmlString = responseFromServer;

            //Console.WriteLine ("----\n {0}\n -------", xmlString);

            XElement xmlTree = XElement.Parse(xmlString);

            Console.WriteLine (xmlTree);

            reader.Close ();
            response.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

How can i navigate into this XML?

Comment: Not just a dupe but also "How can i navigate into this XML?" is way to vague.

Answer (score 0):

read this MS documentation for an example:

[Querying an XDocument vs. Querying an XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675196.aspx)

It shows you 2 options. Of course you would need to use `XElement.Parse` or `XDocument.Parse` instead of `Load`.